# CSS text-select cursor ie7, strange behavior

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Strange one here, hoping to get some feedback to point me in the right direction.

If my `#wrapper` or any of the child divs do not have a background-color applied to them, ie7 changes the normal "pointer" cursor into a "text-select" cursor when mousing around the page (whether mousing over text or not).

I thought I had fixed the problem a while back, but when I remove the background-color from my `#wrapper` or any of the children divs, the problem reappears.

Just looking for some hints or what I should be checking.

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px; /* using 960.gs */
}

#children {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 940px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Seems to be because the divs "hasLayout", but I'm still not sure how to fix it. See [this link.](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2007/08/IE7_with_haslayout_and_cursor_text_problem.html)

**EDIT 2:**

I can't find any more info on this "ie7 bug." Anyone who has any ideas, or even if you're aware of this bug and can just let me know so I know I'm not crazy. I'm getting really frustrated with Microsoft again. Already cost me an extra few hours of work this week. Seems like it never ends.

**EDIT 3:**

Here's [another link](http://www.mail-archive.com/css-d@lists.css-discuss.org/msg31408.html) of someone having the same problem.

**EDIT 4:**

[STACKOVERFLOW.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) suffers from this bug! So does [mashable.com](http://mashable.com/). I guarantee MANY web devs have this bug on their site and they don't even know it.

Check it out for yourself... hover your cursor around the page of either site. Notice it turns to a text-select cursor when it shouldn't.

Seems like it would be easy to fix with the `cursor` property, but the problem would be triggering proper text-select-cursor behavior when required.

Comment: Could you point to a live example? I'm not sure the problem is in those lines...

Comment: Yep, live example at the link I just posted. Download the file on the test page and open 'er up in ie7 to see it firsthand.

Comment: You're not crazy. And I found other issues that hasLayout causes, but no solution yet.

Comment: I found this hope it helps:

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Try these, do the first one (I don't really like it because it uses a conditional comment):
http://bytesizecss.com/blog/post/fix-haslayout-with-one-line-of-css
http://csscreator.com/node/25082
http://www.brunildo.org/test/BackgroundBorderLayout.html

Comment: I think the problem is that the divs already HAVE hasLayout (width). Hehe, that's the problem. I need to remove it.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem? Why does the cursor matter?

Comment: Are you asking this because it's a bug that, for the good of mankind, a fix should be found for, or is there a particular issue you're trying to solve? (E.g. is the wrong cursor just unsightly, or does mess up accessibility for some user group?). Knowing this might help us come up with a compromise.

Comment: I was asking because I am a perfectionist and was trying to make my WordPress "framework" look/behave exactly the same in as many browsers as possible. IE7 is a very popular browser, and will be for some time, so I was hoping to find an amicable fix for a "bug/oddity" that not many folks seemed to be aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it too hacky to explicitly state what cursor should go where?

```
html {
    cursor: default;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, li, label, td, th {
    cursor: text;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

etc..

Comment: That still doesn't entirely fix it. The text cursor then appears on the entire block, including any padding and blank space on a partly filled last line, for example, instead of just the actual text.

Comment: Agreed. Great idea, one I've already tried, but doesn't cut it for the reason cited by mercator.

Comment: Hmmm, need it *that* precise, do we? Oh dear.. please see my comment on the question requesting a bit more info on the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I have encountered it before, but it's probably a bit too subtle to really notice during some superficial browser testing. But I've certainly also had issues fixed by setting a background color.

As far as I can tell, the best way to fix it is to position the element causing the problems, or add a positioned wrapper div around it. You would most likely use `position: relative`, though `absolute` and `fixed` should work too.

Positioning the element itself usually works, but adding a wrapper div might work more consistently.

E.g. adding `position: relative` to the `.post-text` class fixes the cursor on the questions and answers on this page.

Comment: Adding `position: relative;` to my #wrapper made no difference for me. As for wrapping my wrapper, well, I guess I'd rather live with the cursor oddity. =)

Comment: Fair enough. I'm curious, though, does adding the extra positioned wrapper fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The transparent 1x1 px GIF works and is also an excellent fix for [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246495/why-do-links-on-my-transparent-div-become-unclickable-in-ie) and other bugs in IE 6 through 8. I would add something like this to my conditional comments for all IE:

```
* {
    background: url('images/fix1.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `background-color:transparent;` explicitly? Does that help?

Comment: Yeppers, tried it. Doesn't work. I guess I'm hoping someone can give me something to "Google." Seems strange that not many folks have experienced this before.

Comment: Too bad: I thought transparent would be enough of a "background" to keep it from happening. I'm assuming you don't want any background? Otherwise, you could add one in a IE7 style sheet via conditional comments. Seems one of those rendering bugs for which there are no decent workarounds. (Javascript?) Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Yeah, my only idea so far is to muck up my CSS and put a `background-color` that matches the main part of my site -- JUST FOR IE7, Lol.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like an ugly hack, but have you tried setting a transparent 1x1 px GIF (AKA spacer) as background?

Comment: Haven't tried that, but if it comes to that, I think I'd rather just set a background-color instead. Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but for this little example it seems to work for IE 7.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; width: 140px;">
   <div style="position: relative; display: inline;">
      <p>
         Here is some test text that will wrap.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea why this seems to work, and it is certainly not ideal.  For some reason putting the p element in an inline relatively positioned div makes the mouse cursor behave more like I'd expect.

I'm not sure that this works in a broader sense though when there is a hierarchy of elements.

I realize this is not a perfect answer, but it might spur other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Delilah's solution, only a little bit simplified works great for me and also solves mercator's issue.

```
div { cursor: default; }
div * { cursor: auto; }
```

The problem is you have to create another css file and address it using conditional comments not to brake other browsers.

PS: This issue becomes very annoying with dark background websites.