# Why do links on my transparent div become unclickable in IE?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, png

Links on my website: http://rnmtest.co.uk/oddfellows/

If you hit 'Dine' you should see a 'Book Now' button.  This element is not clickable in IE.  The area below it has a semi-transparent png as the background.  The content is loaded via jQuery.

I have put the anchor within a container div as recommended by other websites, but this has had no effect.  If I resize the window in IE8 I can sometime click a small portion of the button.

This effect occurs on all anchors, not just the images.

Comment: don't know about that clicking, but please, add `.stop()` before all animations - i clicked few times quickly and it just gave me headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the link position:relative; explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of IE6 - links within a container that use filters to create transparent backgrounds are not clickable
You can find [more information and a workaround here](http://www.hrunting.org/csstests/iealpha.html)

Comment: This isn't an IE6 issue, it's the same in IE7 and IE8.  That workaround has already been applied but doesn't have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

Once you loaded the content from jquery did you hook in the click event?
Did you make sure jquery finished loading the content before you tried to hook the event?
It's very easy to do.